# SQL: Finding all members of a group when they are only listed in pairs, and not all pairs are listed

Tags: sql

I have some data that looks like this, and identifies pairs that are related:

```
From_ID   To_ID
   A        C
   B        C
   D        E
   E        D (note this is the same pair as above, in a different order)
   E        F
   A        F
   G        H
```

Using the logic of 'if x is paired with y, and y is paired with z, then x is paired with z', how can I run an SQL query to return all members of a group?

So for the table above I would like a set of results that identifies or returns two groups: 'A, B, C, D, E, F' and 'G, H', not fussy about how this is done.

It feels like some kind of iterative query but I really have no idea where to start with this so any pointers would be appreciated.

edit: could be run in SQL Developer or HiveQL.

Comment: This requires a recursive CTE or hierarchical query, the syntax of which depends on your database (even if it is supported).

Comment: `G` and `H` are membes of the group (G, H), aren't they?

Comment: Could run it in SQL Developer or HiveQL.

Comment: Oracle and Hive are two VERY different animals. You should make up your mind on which one is it.

Comment: The data currently sits in Hive but I can load it into Oracle if necessary/easier. Yes (G, H) is one group.